# equal_range on one key, lower/upper bound on another in boost multi_index_container composite_key

Tags: c++, boost, composite-key, boost-multi-index

Suppose I have the following:

```
struct Person
{
    std::string mName;
    Birthday mBirthday;
};

using namespace boost::mult_index;
typedef multi_index_container<
    Person,
    ordered_non_unique<
        composite_key<
            Person,
            member<Person, std::string, &Person::mName>,
            member<Person, Birthday, &Person::mBirthday>
        > // composite_key
    >  // ordered_non-unique
> PersonContainer; // mult_index_container

PersonContainer personContainer;

...

std::pair<PersonContainer::iterator, PersonContainer::iterator> similarPeople
    = personContainer.equal_range(boost::make_tuple("Bob","01/15/65"));
```

This would give me an iterator range where each iterator pointed to a Person named 'Bob' born on '01/15/65'.

What if I want an iterator range that gave me all the people in the container named 'Bob' but born *between* '01/01/65' and '01/31/65'? This is effectively an equal_range on 'Bob' but a lower and upper bound on birthdays. Is this possible? If so please explain how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The range you want is [`lower_bound(make_tuple("Bob","01/01/65"))`,`upper_bound(make_tuple("Bob","01/31/65"))`).